# apscheduler I can't remove running job

Tags: python, flask, scheduled-tasks, gunicorn, apscheduler

I try to schedule a function execution using BackgroundScheduler, I can add a job, and it seems to work, but if i try to do any actions like remove_job, reschedule_job and so one, these actions have no effect on it, and the job is still running.

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

fatturazione = Blueprint("fatturazione", __name__)
def importazione_ordini():
   print('Hello')
   return

scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(importazione_ordini,'interval', minutes=5, id='my_job')
scheduler.start()

@fatturazione.route('/fatturazione/remove_job', methods=['GET,POST'])
def remove_job():
try:
  print('before remove', scheduler.get_jobs())
  scheduler.remove_job('my_job')
  print('after remove', scheduler.get_jobs()) # is empty now
except Exception as e:
  print(e)

@fatturazione.route('/fatturazione/reschedule_job', methods=['GET,POST'])
def reschedule_job():
interval = request.json['interval']
try:
  scheduler.reschedule_job('my_job', trigger= 'interval', hours= int(interval['hours']), minutes=int(interval['minutes']))
except Exception as e:
  print(e)
```

Debug:

```
before remove [<Job (id=my_job name=importazione_ordini)>]
after remove []
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Nov/2021 16:40:50] "POST /fatturazione/remove_job 
HTTP/1.1" 200 -
before remove []
Error in job removing 'No job by the id of my_job was found'
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Nov/2021 16:41:01] "POST /fatturazione/remove_job 
HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Hello
^C(env) gabriele@gabriele-Virtual-Machine:~/webapp$ python3 main.py 
runserver --noreload
```

Comment: I have a hunch that ```scheduler.get_jobs()``` above moved before ```scheduler.remove_job('my_job')``` would also be empty. Please post the rest of your initialization code - the main function - and the output of your debugging.

Comment: Posting the debug output in an image offsite is not cool. Copy and paste it in your code above as well.

Comment: I have added more details to my question. scheduler.get_jobs () before the remove_job function, returns the object 'my_job', while after scheduler.get_jobs () return an empty array, so the removal of the job is successful, but seems to have no effect on the background process

Comment: How would you propose for APScheduler to stop a function running in a worker thread?